# implementing << and >> with &, |, ^, ~ only?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, logical-operators, bit-shift, discrete-mathematics

Can bitwise left-shift (`<<`) and right-shift (`>>`) operators be implemented using only AND (`&`), OR (`|`), XOR (`^`), NOT (`~`)?

Comment: No. At minimum you need one operation where the result for one bit can influence what happens with a neighboring bit.

Comment: @njuffa Now that I think about, yes, you're right; there'd be no way to influence neighboring bits.